# While loop program for parentheses

Tags: python, while-loop

This is my new code. I have adjusted it but it shows me Parentheses balanced at all times.

```
parentheses_string = input('Enter string:\n')
i = 0
count = 0
while i<len(parentheses_string):
   if (parentheses_string[i] == '('):
       open_count = count+1
   if (parentheses_string[i] == ')'):
       close_count = count+1
   i = i+1
if open_count==close_count:
    print('Parentheses balanced')
else:
    print('Parentheses unbalanced')
```

Comment: You should do `i = i+1` only once at the end of the loop's body. Think what would happen if you have a string like `"("`.

Comment: Please post the full error.

Comment: The `if open_count==close_count:` check and subsequent `print` calls are inside the loop and thus will happen every iteration.

Comment: "it shows me Parentheses balanced at all times" - no it doesn't. It gives a name error

Comment: I've been trying to make it work but I'm not sure where the problem is originating from

Answer (score 0):

`count` is 0 and is never changed. Therefore, `open_count` will either be undefined if no `(` is in the string or it will be 1 but nothing else. Same for `close_count`.

When it comes to the comparison, it will either raise a `NameError` or compare 1 against 1.

IMHO the code could be much simpler in many ways.

1. no need to count open and closing parens. Just increase and decrease `count`.
2. make a look over the characters in the string, not go via index. Use a for loop when you know the number of iterations in advance (which is the case here). Use a while loop when the number of iterations is not known before.
3. Get rid of redundant parenthenses in your code

```
parentheses_string = input('Enter string:\n')
count = 0
for char in parentheses_string:
    if char == "(":
        count += 1
    if char == ")":
        count -= 1
if count == 0:
    print('Parentheses balanced')
else:
    print('Parentheses unbalanced')
```

The code may still fail if you want to check text like `)(`.

Answer (score 0):

Use one counter, initialized to `0`. `Add 1` for each `(`, `subtract 1` for each `)`.
If the result is `zero` and `never went negative` then the parenthesis are balanced.

```
def check_balance(string):
    """return 0 if parentheses are balanced."""
    
    balance = 0
    for char in string:
        if char in "()":
            if char == "(":
                balance += 1
            else:
                balance -= 1
            if balance < 0:
                break  # too much ')'
    return balance

if check_balance(string):
    print('unbalanced')
else:
    print('balanced')
```

Answer (score 0):

By converting all opening parentheses to 1 and closing parentheses to -1 you can perform the verification using the cumulative sum of these mapped values.  The parentheses will be balanced if the cumulative levels never go below 0 and the final sum is zero:

```
from itertools import accumulate
def balanced(S):
    levels = [(c=="(")-(c==")") for c in S]
    return sum(levels)==0 and -1 not in accumulate(levels)
```